# How to implement security on a page shared by token on Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

**The need :**

I need to share a "client" page for `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` users of my Symfony3 application.

What are the good practices to implement this kind of feature ?

---

**My thoughts :**

1. Specific access control in security.yaml

   access_control:

   ```
   - { path: {regex with token?}, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   ```
2. Token entity to store the token
3. findOnBy with the token passed in url

   ```
   if(null === $token){
       throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page not found');
   }
   ```

---

**Questions :**

1. The regex is not working what would be a corresponding regex for
   `case/{token}` ?
2. I have the feeling that this method works but is not very effective
   in terms of security requirement. Is my idea sufficient to manage
   security on this feature ? What would be a better practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the authentication outside of your controller, and return a proper "not authorized" exception if the token is not valid.

Basically you will need to create an implementation of `AuthenticatorInterface`, which is usually accomplished by extending `AbstractGuardAuthenticator` as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html).

In your `supports()` method you will likely check the existence of that token, and probably that the route is the one you really want to protect/authenticate.

Comment: What about the secutity.yaml ? is it good that way ? If yes do you have an idea for the regex ? Thanks for the AuthenticatorInterface tips. I'll implement that